# how to create a virtual joystick in Android custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view, joystick

I want to make a virtual joystick. There are so many libs available but I want something like in the attached images.
[image]

Pic1 is when the joystick is not touched, and when the joystick is touched and dragged the circle becomes the ellipse and follows the finger. please help me if there is any library or any other way to solve it.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Android has a drag/drop framework that has listeners for drag event and drop event. On drag of a view, you can even get the location and you can set the bounds for a view to be dragged. Details are here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html
2. You can also use the Android's spring animation to move back a View back to its original position when released. Details are here -https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/spring-animation.html#lifecycle-of-spring-animation

So to make a joystick like the way you want, you can drag your Image to a certain point and have a spring animation attached so that it goes back to origin once released. And using listeners for the drag event, you can get the coordinates of the Image when it is being dragged or after being released.

Comment: thanks for your effort but please look at the images, PIC1 & PIC2 . How to implement that change in middle circle to ellipse when dragged?

Comment: when you start dragging, onDrag() method is called. Just change the ImageView background inside onDrag().